# Partitioned List<T>?

Tags: c#, linq, collections, partitioning

I have a large list of objects where I sometimes need to iterate over the entire list and sometimes I only want to look at objects where .Property="somevalue".

Currently I look over my collection `.Where(_ => _.Property="value_i_need")` which is expensive if I have 100k objects loaded and only a handful are in my target group.

So what I'd like to do is keep the list segmented maybe as a `Dictionary<string, List<T>>` so that I can quickly refer to only the set of objects I want, but if I do this, how can enumerate all the objects in all the dictionaries using Linq without using more memory to maintain a regular list?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well it sounds like you want a `Lookup`:

```
var lookup = list.ToLookup(x => x.Property);
```

You can easily iterate over the whole collection by just flattening:

```
foreach (var entry in lookup.SelectMany(x => x))
{
}
```

... but this *won't* be in the initial list order (unless you're very lucky :) If you need to maintain the original list order, you'll need to do a bit more work...

Comment: Perfect - I hadn't used ToLookup or SelectMany before but that'll do it. Thanks.

Comment: Nice, I didn't know that Lookup stuff

Answer (score 1):

Why not simply make it simple, and store those specific objects in another list ?

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you could do it with a dictionary:

(Customer and CustomerStatus for example):

```
public class Customer
{
    public string Name
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public CustomerStatus Status
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}

public enum CustomerStatus
{
    Pending = 0,
    Active = 1,
    Deleted = 2
}

// Create the dictionary based upon the "filters":
var dictionary = new Dictionary<CustomerStatus, ICollection<Customer>>();
dictionary.Add(CustomerStatus.Active, new List<Customer>());
dictionary.Add(CustomerStatus.Deleted, new List<Customer>());
dictionary.Add(CustomerStatus.Pending, new List<Customer>());

// Add some customers:
dictionary[CustomerStatus.Active].Add(new Customer
{
    Name = "Active 1"
});
dictionary[CustomerStatus.Active].Add(new Customer
{
    Name = "Active 2"
});
dictionary[CustomerStatus.Deleted].Add(new Customer
{
    Name = "Deleted"
});
dictionary[CustomerStatus.Pending].Add(new Customer
{
    Name = "Pending"
});

// Enumerate specific filter or all.
System.Console.WriteLine("Active Customers Only");
foreach (var customer in dictionary[CustomerStatus.Active])
{
    System.Console.WriteLine(customer.Name);
}

System.Console.WriteLine("---");

var allCustomers = dictionary.SelectMany(x => x.Value);

System.Console.WriteLine("All Customers");
foreach (var customer in allCustomers)
{
    System.Console.WriteLine(customer.Name);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could have all the objects in one list, plus a dictionary of list indexes.

```
var list = new List<MyType>();

// Fill the list
...

// Create the index dictionary
var propIndexes = list
    .Select((obj, i) => new { obj.Property, i })
    .GroupBy(x => x.Property)
    .ToDictionary(g => g.Key,
                  g => g.Select(x => x.i).ToList());

// Iterate the objects having one specific property
foreach (int i in propIndexes["value_i_need"]) {
    Console.WriteLine(list[i]);
}
```